# How to make this kind of button?

Tags: java

I am creating a currency converter and I want to create a button that switches or swaps values. I appreciate the support.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRJcq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just simple `ImageButton`

You can set this button using following code :

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/home" /> <!--Add Your Icon Here In Drawable-->
```

After that, Just set simple `View.OnClickListener()`

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Handle Your Click Here
            }
        });
```